# Supertabular with output overlapping

Tags: supertabular

I am using supertabular but it is showing error like this:

> Misplaced \noalign
>
> \ST@next....& \tsbp $i$ \ \hline \tbsp \noalign
>
> {\global \let \=\@savcr}

With the output in dvi/pdf with the second page overlapping on the first. Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentstyle[10pt,epsfig]{aa}
\include{bk_macros}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\newcommand{\tbsp}{\rule{0pt}{18pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{\hline\hline \tbsp Serial No. & \tbsp Name & \tbsp Type & \tbsp $q=\frac{m_2}{m_1}$  & \tbsp $\Omega_{inner}$ & \tbsp $\Omega_{outer}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,1}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,2}$ & \tbsp $i$ \\ \hline\tbsp}
\tablehead{\hline  \hline \tbsp Serial No. & \tbsp Name & \tbsp Type & \tbsp $q=\frac{m_2}{m_1}$  & \tbsp $\Omega_{inner}$ & \tbsp $\Omega_{outer}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,1}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,2}$ & \tbsp $i$ \\ \hline\tbsp}
\tabletail{\hline  \multicolumn{8}{c}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\}
\tablelasttail{\hline\hline}
\topcaption{List of Binary stars considered for the present study along with input parameters and type}              % title of Table
\label{table:1} 
\par
\begin{supertabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & ABAnd\_Hrivnak 1988V & OC & 2.0367 & 5.303534 & 4.705244 & 5450 & 5821 & 86.800 \\
2 & ANAnd\_Giuricin 1982V & D & 0.6 & 3.063442 & 2.712371 & 7800 & 5960 & 78.6 \\
3 & BXAnd\_Samec 1989V & C & 0.497 & 2.870075 & 2.573097 & 6600 & 4800 & 75.5 \\
4 & CNAnd\_vanHamme 2001V & NC & 0.3885 & 2.654548 & 2.416987 & 6500 & 5922 & 68.510 \\
5 & RTAnd\_Kjurkchieva 2001V & OC & 0.74 & 3.31343 & 2.892087 & 6150 & 4920 & 82 \\
6 & AdBoo\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.86 & 2.654548 & 2.416987 & 6500 & 5922 & 68.510 \\
7 & RSCha\_Clausen 1980V & D & 0.98 & 3.717427 & 3.183237 & 7950 & 7537 & 83.7 \\
8 & RZCha\_Giuricin 1980V & D & 1.006 & 7.82 & 5.903 & 6360 & 6410 & 84.4 \\
9 & KPAql\_Ibanoglu 1974V & D & 0.988 & 3.730474 & 8.755561 & 7400 & 7400 & 90 \\
10 & V1182Aql\_Bell 1987V & D & 0.36 & 2.595349 & 2.373841 & 35600 & 27470 & 61.3 \\
11 & V417Aql\_Samec 1997V & OC & 2.714 & 6.234823 & 6.118133 & 6030 & 6256 & 84.470 \\
12 & BWAqr\_Clausen 1991V & D & 1.07 & 13.934064 & 11.634127 & 6450 & 6350 & 88.40 \\
13 & CXAqr\_McFarlanc 1986V & NC & 0.59 & 3.294 & 3.045062 & 6400 & 4900 & 86.2 \\
14 & DVAqr\_Okazaki 1985V & D & 0.6 & 3.538634 & 3.7 & 7600 & 5200 & 70 \\
15 & EEAqr\_Hilditch 1988V & NC & 0.32 & 2.510013 & 2.535297 & 7060 & 4395 & 80.5 \\
16 & RYAqr\_Helt 1987bV & SD & 0.201 & 6.051 & 2.256 & 7600 & 4550 & 82.6 \\
17 & V535Ara\_Schoffel 1979V & OC & 0.311 & 2.465 & 2.465 & 8200 & 8125 & 81 \\
18 & V539Ara\_Clausen 1996bV & D & 0.85 & 3.709914 & 2.935106 & 17900 & 17056 & 85.2 \\
19 & SSAri\_Kim 2003V & OC & 3.255 & 6.951823 & 6.329282 & 5860 & 6144 & 74.620 \\
20 & AHAur\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 0.169 & 2.153701 & 2.045107 & 6215 & 6141 & 75.460 \\
21 & ARAur\_Nordstrom 1994V & D & 0.925 & 3.627072 & 3.117964 & 11125 & 10600 & 88.520 \\
22 & ARAur\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.977 & 3.712529 & 3.179695 & 5346 & 5200 & 89.7 \\
23 & IMAur\_Gulmen 1985V & D & 0.353 & 2.580614 & 2.363079 & 10350 & 5095 & 78 \\
24 & SXAur\_Chambliss 1979V & NC & 0.5986 & 3.060873 & 2.710523 & 19200 & 14804 & 82 \\
25 & AWCam\_Russo 1983V & NC & 0.22 & 2.281758 & 2.142056 & 9900 & 6422 & 75.36 \\
26 & AYCam\_Williamon 2004V & D & 0.8972 & 3.580942 & 3.084681 & 7250 & 7395 & 88.465 \\
27 & DNCam\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 2.3753 & 5.774655 & 5.167444 & 6700 & 6840 & 71.2 \\
28 & FNCam\_Pribulla 2002V & OC & 0.222 & 2.86586 & 2.145680 & 6848 & 6700 & 71.2 \\
29 & EMCar\_Andersen 1989V & D & 1.016 & 3.824992 & 3.206900 & 34000 & 34000 & 81.5 \\
30 & QXCar\_Andersen 1983cv & D & 0.914 & 5.091186 & 2.718311 & 23500 & 22240 & 85.7 \\
31 & AOCas\_Schneider 1978V & OC & 1.185 & 4.034 & 4.034 & 34700 & 35033 & 51.2 \\
32 & MUCas\_Lacy 2004V & D & 1.019 & 4.747435 & 2.923388 & 15100 & 14750 & 87.02 \\
33 & TWCas\_Narita 2001V & SD & 0.432 & 2.742677 & 2.480979 & 10500 & 5400 & 74.7 \\
34 & V459Cas\_Lacy 2004V & D & 0.974 & 3.806169 & 3.128686 & 9141 & 9099 & 89.465 \\
35 & V523Cas\_Samec 2005V & OC & 0.52 & 2.983 & 2.604839 & 4762 & 5104 & 85.39 \\
36 & LZCen\_Vaz 1995bv & D & 1.09 & 3.950986 & 3.343726 & 26430 & 26500 & 72.22 \\
37 & SZCen\_Gronbech 1977V & D & 1.016 & 3.77775954 & 3.231265 & 8000 & 8280 & 88.08 \\
38 & V346Cen\_Gimenez 1986bv & D & 0.71 & 4.677327 & 2.511337 & 26500 & 24000 & 83.9 \\
39 & V753Cen\_Barone 1993V & OC & 3.15 & 6.814164 & 6.193046 & 5955 & 6221 & 81.660 \\
40 & V752Cen\_Leung 1976V & OC & 3.344 & 7.067997 & 6.444314 & 6210 & 6300 & 83.18 \\
41 & V757Cen\_Maceroni 1984V & OC & 1.49 & 4.511196 & 3.934232 & 5927 & 6000 & 69.31 \\
42 & AHCep\_Holmgren 1990V & D & 0.877 & 3.547218 & 3.060365 & 29900 & 28570 & 29.21 \\
43 & CWCep\_Clausen 1991bv & D & 0.94 & 3.769554 & 3.080072 & 28300 & 27700 & 82.5 \\
44 & EKCep\_Hill 1984V & D & 0.55 & 3.363822 & 2.504025 & 8995 & 5689 & 89.16 \\
45 & GKCep\_Niarchos 1991V & NC & 0.92 & 3.618779 & 3.111993 & 9500 & 9000 & 73.5 \\
46 & NYCep\_Ahn 1992V & D & 0.72 & 6.524666 & 2.389262 & 28800 & 23000 & 77.39 \\
47 & V497Cep\_Yakut 2003V & D & 0.782 & 3.386104 & 2.944357 & 19500 & 17756 & 57.9 \\
48 & TWCet\_Russo 1982V & OC & 1.664 & 4.758601 & 4.183495 & 5400 & 5600 & 85 \\
49 & CWCMa\_Terrell 1992V & D & 0.944 & 3.658419 & 3.140597 & 10800 & 10300 & 83.3 \\
50 & FZCMa\_Moffat 1983V & D & 1.00 & 3.75 & 3.206796 & 22000 & 20596 & 87.63 \\
51 & GZCMa\_Popper 1985V & D & 0.909 & 3.600561 & 3.098834 & 8810 & 8531 & 86.6 \\
52 & SWCMa\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.914 & 5.4043 & 2.680445 & 8500 & 8500 & 88.72 \\
53 & TYCrA\_Casey 1998V & D & 0.521 & 2.915985 & 2.60621 & 12000 & 4900 & 83 \\
54 & RTCrB\_Sabby 2003V & D & 1.011 & 3.757853 & 3.223625 & 5075 & 5781 & 84.9 \\
55 & AlCru\_Bell 1987V & NC & 0.61 & 3.081744 & 2.725534 & 24200 & 17660 & 81 \\
56 & DKCyg\_Mochnacki 1972V & OC & 0.325 & 2.520836 & 2.319312 & 7200 & 7200 & 82 \\
57 & MRCyg\_Linnell 1998V & SD & 0.399 & 2.676056 & 2.432628 & 20900 & 13900 & 84.4 \\
58 & SWCyg\_Wilson 1988V & DC & 0.3664 & 8.938885 & 2.383622 & 9070 & 3813 & 82.7 \\
59 & V1073Cyg\_Ahn 1992V & OC & 0.32 & 2.510013 & 2.311367 & 6856 & 6740 & 69.4 \\
60 & V1143Cyg\_VanHamme 1984V & D & 0.9792 & 8.379136 & 2.565819 & 6550 & 6496 & 87.035 \\
61 & V1425Cyg\_Hill 1993V & NC & 0.641 & 3.138012 & 3.134766 & 15230 & 11733 & 71.15 \\
62 & V380Cyg\_Guinan 2000V & D & 0.626 & 4.034862 & 2.469972 & 21350 & 20500 & 82.4 \\
63 & V382Cyg\_Harries 1997V & OC & 0.7418 & 3.316565 & 2.894341 & 36000 & 35000 & 84.5 \\
64 & V442Cyg\_Lacy 1987V & D & 0.902 & 3.58893 & 3.090443 & 6900 & 6725 & 86 \\
65 & V470Cyg\_Russo 1982V & D & 0.877 & 3.547218 & 3.060365 & 21100 & 1961 & 50 \\
66 & V477Cyg\_Degirmenci 2003V & D & 0.677 & 3.202518 & 2.812357 & 36100 & 34758 & 85.7 \\
67 & V478Cyg\_Sezer 1983V & D & 0.9717 & 3.824019 & 3.116297 & 30900 & 30308 & 78.07 \\
68 & V541Cyg\_Lacy 1998V & D & 1.00 & 7.421249 & 2.624289 & 9885 & 9954 & 89.88 \\
69 & V729Cyg\_Leung 1978V & OC & 0.23 & 2.305774 & 2.160058 & 34300 & 22735 & 68.18 \\
70 & V836Cyg\_Breinhorst 1989V & NC & 0.33 & 2.531613 & 2.327215 & 10333 & 6000 & 8.08 \\
71 & V885Cyg\_Lacy 2004V & D & 1.1142 & 3.933351 & 3.38026 & 7950 & 8375 & 7.064 \\
72 & V909Cyg\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.886 & 3.562265 & 3.071213 & 9705 & 8790 & 89.2 \\
73 & BSDra\_Russo 1981V & D & 0.999 & 3.748375 & 3.20562 & 6750 & 6740 & 89.4 \\
74 & EFDra\_Pribulla 2001V & OC & 0.16 & 2.129956 & 2.026929 & 6000 & 6054 & 78.13 \\
75 & FUDra\_Vanco 2001V & OC & 3.9841 & 7.891422 & 7.260916 & 5800 & 6133 & 78.64 \\
76 & RZDra\_Kreiner 1994V & C & 0.396 & 2.669927 & 2.428173 & 8150 & 4898 & 87 \\
77 & UZDra\_Lacy 1989V & D & 0.92 & 3.618799 & 3.111993 & 6100 & 5844 & 89.32 \\
78 & ASEri\_VanHamme 1984V & SD & 0.1144 & 2.002505 & 1.928049 & 8500 & 5000 & 80.018 \\
79 & TZFor\_Andersen 1991V & D & 0.951 & 3.669932 & 3.148912 & 6470 & 4960 & 85.67 \\
80 & AFGem\_Maxted 1995V & SD & 0.342 & 2.557294 & 2.346025 & 10000 & 5400 & 87.4 \\
81 & ADHer\_Mardirossian 1980V & SD & 0.33 & 2.531613 & 2.327215 & 8610 & 3900 & 84.1 \\
82 & DIHer\_Popper 1982V & D & 0.88 & 7.181783 & 2.519301 & 17000 & 15100 & 89.3 \\
83 & V624Her\_Popper 1984V & D & 0.825 & 3.459566 & 2.997222 & 8150 & 7940 & 79.4 \\
84 & V728Her\_Nelson 1995V & OC & 5.5991 & 9.8987 & 9.257568 & 6622 & 6787 & 69.2 \\
85 & V899Her\_Ozdermir 2002V & OC & 0.566 & 3.000627 & 2.667176 & 5700 & 5500 & 65.772 \\
86 & AlHya\_Popper 1988V & D & 0.923 & 4.780037 & 2.776981 & 7096 & 6699 & 90 \\
87 & Chi2Hya\_Clausen\&Nordstrom 1978V & D & 0.73 & 3.295982 & 2.879543 & 11550 & 11100 & 77.9 \\
88 & HSHya\_Torres 1997V & D & 0.971 & 3.702721 & 3.172606 & 6500 & 6400 & 85.56 \\
89 & KWHya\_Andersen 1984bv & D & 0.753 & 3.709655 & 2.761849 & 8000 & 6881 & 87.65 \\
90 & RSInd\_Hilditch 1988V & NC & 0.322 & 2.514348 & 2.31455 & 7200 & 4659 & 90 \\
91 & V364Lac\_Torres 1999V & D & 1.016 & 5.399183 & 2.811273 & 8251 & 8500 & 89.19 \\
92 & EXLeo\_Pribulla 1988V & OC & 0.199 & 2.230239 & 2.103257 & 6330 & 6167 & 61.1 \\
93 & TXLeo\_Srivastava 1968V & D & 0.375 & 2.810022 & 2.325959 & 8810 & 6476 & 66.8 \\
94 & UVLeo\_Frederik 1996V & D & 0.965 & 3.6929 & 3.165508 & 5920 & 5821 & 82.63 \\
95 & UZLeo\_Bradatreet 2004V & OC & 0.303 & 2.472848 & 2.28404 & 7250 & 7250 & 83 \\
96 & TLMi\_Cester 1979V & SD & 0.1 & 1.959104 & 1.8938 & 9860 & 5055 & 86.3 \\
97 & GGLup\_Andersen 1993V & D & 0.61 & 3.669024 & 2.53152 & 14000 & 11200 & 86.75 \\
98 & SWLyn\_Broadstreet 2004V & NC & 0.524 & 2.921685 & 2.610318 & 6700 & 4220 & 82 \\
99 & UULyn\_Yamasaki 1983V & NC & 0.41 & 2.698423 & 2.448877 & 6700 & 3500 & 83 \\
100 & UVLyn\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 2.7248 & 6.249339 & 5.634983 & 6045 & 6262 & 66.8 \\
101 & FLLyn\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.786 & 3.392981 & 2.949301 & 6152 & 5297 & 86.3 \\
102 & TZMen\_Andersen 1987V & D & 0.604 & 3.190981 & 2.664619 & 10400 & 7200 & 88.73 \\
103 & UXMen\_Andersen 1989V & D & 0.968 & 3.708102 & 3.163838 & 6194 & 6152 & 89.6 \\
104 & ARMon\_Popper 1976V & D & 1.062 & 3.850078 & 3.301308 & 4200 & 5800 & 86 \\
105 & DDMon\_Qian 1997V & SD & 0.45 & 2.778437 & 2.506876 & 6600 & 5118 & 76.5 \\
106 & DDMon\_Yamasaki 1990V & SD & 0.697 & 3.237989 & 2.837854 & 6600 & 5514 & 79.26 \\
107 & FSMon\_Lacy 2000V & D & 0.8959 & 3.578777 & 3.08312 & 6715 & 6550 & 87.7 \\
108 & VVMon\_Popper 1988V & D & 1.062 & 3.850078 & 3.301308 & 4200 & 5800 & 86 \\
109 & TUMus\_Wilson 1981V & OC & 0.7207 & 3.279704 & 2.86784 & 33600 & 29194 & 75.87 \\
110 & TVMus\_Hilditch 1989V & OC & 0.135 & 2.061727 & 1.974287 & 5980 & 6088 & 78.9 \\
111 & V1010Oph\_Leung 1974V & NC & 0.487 & 2.850776 & 2.559166 & 7500 & 5100 & 86.05 \\
112 & V2388Oph\_Rodriguez 1998V & OC & 0.186 & 2.197533& 2.078487 & 6450 & 6130 & 83.9 \\
113 & V451Oph\_Clausen 1986V & OC & 0.85 & 3.549319 & 3.004555 & 10800 & 10000 & 85.9 \\
114 & V502Oph\_Maceroni 1982V & D & 2.985 & 6.596452 & 5.977753 & 5954 & 6200 & 71.67 \\
115 & V508Oph\_Lapasset 1990V & OC & 0.53 & 2.933059 & 2.618516 & 6000 & 5830 & 86.13 \\
116 & EWOri\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.97 & 3.989242 & 3.046496 & 5970 & 5781 & 89.65 \\
117 & GCOri\_Torres 2000V & D & 0.9982 & 4.885313 & 2.859927 & 9950 & 9950 & 89.24 \\
118 & V1031Ori\_Andersen 1990V & D & 1.034 & 4.755166 & 2.94946 & 6310 & 5010 & 88.45 \\
119 & IQPer\_Lacy 1985V & D & 0.493 & 3.411177 & 2.470213 & 12300 & 8100 & 89.3 \\
120 & ALPhe\_Andersen 1988V & D & 1.034 & 4.755166 & 2.94946 & 6310 & 5010 & 88.45 \\
121 & ZetaPhe\_Clausen 1976V & D & 0.649 & 3.191342 & 2.757983 & 14000 & 11700 & 87.7 \\
122 & VZPsc\_Hrivnak 1995V & NC & 0.8 & 3.416971 & 2.966562 & 4500 & 4110 & 48 \\
123 & PVPup\_Vaz 1984V & D & 0.993 & 3.949822 & 3.102736 & 6920 & 6931 & 83.09 \\
124 & UZPup\_Malasan 1989V & OC & 0.85 & 3.501861 & 3.027682 & 8150 & 7300 & 84.0 \\
125 & VPup\_Andersen 1983V & SD & 0.53 & 2.933059 & 2.618516 & 27000 & 24354 & 79 \\
126 & RZPyx\_Bell 1987V & NC & 0.82 & 3.451072 & 2.991107 & 17000 & 16760 & 87.4 \\
127 & TyPyx\_Andersen 1981bV & D & 0.98 & 3.717427 & 3.183237 & 5400 & 5340 & 87.88 \\
128 & VVPyx\_Andersen 1984V & D & 1.00 & 4.172674 & 3.034401 & 9506 & 9506 & 88.075 \\
129 & RTScl\_Broadstreet 2004V & C & 0.433 & 2.744674 & 2.482426 & 7000 & 5200 & 79 \\
130 & V701Sco\_Bell 1987V & OC & 0.99 & 3.733732 & 3.195028 & 23500 & 23500 & 65 \\
131 & V760Sco\_Andersen 1985bV & D & 0.928 & 3.737653 & 3.071251 & 16900 & 16300 & 82.17 \\
132 & V7906Sco\_Alencar 1997V & D & 1.0395 & 3.820337 & 3.255917 & 10700 & 10550 & 76 \\
133 & RZSct\_Wilson 1985V & OC & 0.277 & 6.062884 & 2.241216 & 22700 & 7500 & 83.1 \\
134 & OUSer\_Pribulla 2002V & OC & 0.173 & 2.16413 & 2.053069 & 6380 & 5960 & 54.23 \\
135 & V1647Sgr\_Clausen 1977V & D & 0.901 & 6.271572 & 2.590086 & 10000 & 9500 & 90 \\
136 & V1647Sgr\_Vaz 1997V & D & 0.6993 & 3.242052 & 2.840774 & 38000 & 34117 & 65.2 \\
137 & V526Sgr\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.74 & 5.451516 & 2.603541 & 10100 & 8450 & 87.3 \\
138 & CDTau\_Ribas 1999V & D & 0.948 & 3.665 & 3.14535 & 6200 & 6200 & 87.7 \\
139 & V471Tau\_Bradstreet 2004V & D & 1.107 & 3.921916 & 3.369402 & 5040 & 34500 & 80 \\
140 & AWUMa\_Pribulla 1999V & OC & 0.0803 & 1.896344 & 1.843663 & 7175 & 7022 & 78.3 \\
141 & TXUMa\_Maxted 1995V & SD & 0.247 & 2.345911 & 2.190033 & 12900 & 5500 & 83.5 \\
142 & CVVel\_Clausen 1977V & D & 0.983 & 3.722322 & 3.186777 & 18200 & 18060 & 86.59 \\
143 & DmVir\_Andersen 1984V & D & 1.004 & 3.756497 & 3.212919 & 6400 & 6400 & 89.66 \\
144 & BPVul\_Lacy 2003V & D & 0.8105 & 3.570372 & 2.917453 & 7709 & 6775 & 87.67 \\
145 & ERVul\_Guinan 1991V & D & 0.9615 & 3.687165 & 3.161363 & 6050 & 6016 & 88.3 \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `bk_macros` contain? Your code is most probably not compilable

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the package `\usepackage{longtable}`, it works with your data. Hope it helps

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %\documentstyle[10pt,epsfig]{aa}
    \include{bk_macros}
    \usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \newcommand{\tbsp}{\rule{0pt}{18pt}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrr}
\caption{List of Binary stars considered for the present study along with input parameters and type}              % title of Table
     Serial No. & \tbsp Name & \tbsp Type & \tbsp $q=\frac{m_2}{m_1}$  & \tbsp $\Omega_{inner}$ & \tbsp $\Omega_{outer}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,1}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,2}$ & \tbsp $i$ \\ \hline\endfirsthead
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{... see next page...} \\ \hline
    Serial No. & \tbsp Name & \tbsp Type & \tbsp $q=\frac{m_2}{m_1}$  & \tbsp $\Omega_{inner}$ & \tbsp $\Omega_{outer}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,1}$ & \tbsp $T_{eff,2}$ & \tbsp $i$ \\ \hline\endhead
    \hline\multicolumn{9}{c}{... end of table...} \\\endlastfoot
            % title of Table
    \label{table:1}


    1 & ABAnd\_Hrivnak 1988V & OC & 2.0367 & 5.303534 & 4.705244 & 5450 & 5821 & 86.800 \\
    2 & ANAnd\_Giuricin 1982V & D & 0.6 & 3.063442 & 2.712371 & 7800 & 5960 & 78.6 \\
    3 & BXAnd\_Samec 1989V & C & 0.497 & 2.870075 & 2.573097 & 6600 & 4800 & 75.5 \\
    4 & CNAnd\_vanHamme 2001V & NC & 0.3885 & 2.654548 & 2.416987 & 6500 & 5922 & 68.510 \\
    5 & RTAnd\_Kjurkchieva 2001V & OC & 0.74 & 3.31343 & 2.892087 & 6150 & 4920 & 82 \\
    6 & AdBoo\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.86 & 2.654548 & 2.416987 & 6500 & 5922 & 68.510 \\
    7 & RSCha\_Clausen 1980V & D & 0.98 & 3.717427 & 3.183237 & 7950 & 7537 & 83.7 \\
    8 & RZCha\_Giuricin 1980V & D & 1.006 & 7.82 & 5.903 & 6360 & 6410 & 84.4 \\
    9 & KPAql\_Ibanoglu 1974V & D & 0.988 & 3.730474 & 8.755561 & 7400 & 7400 & 90 \\
    10 & V1182Aql\_Bell 1987V & D & 0.36 & 2.595349 & 2.373841 & 35600 & 27470 & 61.3 \\
    11 & V417Aql\_Samec 1997V & OC & 2.714 & 6.234823 & 6.118133 & 6030 & 6256 & 84.470 \\
    12 & BWAqr\_Clausen 1991V & D & 1.07 & 13.934064 & 11.634127 & 6450 & 6350 & 88.40 \\
    13 & CXAqr\_McFarlanc 1986V & NC & 0.59 & 3.294 & 3.045062 & 6400 & 4900 & 86.2 \\
    14 & DVAqr\_Okazaki 1985V & D & 0.6 & 3.538634 & 3.7 & 7600 & 5200 & 70 \\
    15 & EEAqr\_Hilditch 1988V & NC & 0.32 & 2.510013 & 2.535297 & 7060 & 4395 & 80.5 \\
    16 & RYAqr\_Helt 1987bV & SD & 0.201 & 6.051 & 2.256 & 7600 & 4550 & 82.6 \\
    17 & V535Ara\_Schoffel 1979V & OC & 0.311 & 2.465 & 2.465 & 8200 & 8125 & 81 \\
    18 & V539Ara\_Clausen 1996bV & D & 0.85 & 3.709914 & 2.935106 & 17900 & 17056 & 85.2 \\
    19 & SSAri\_Kim 2003V & OC & 3.255 & 6.951823 & 6.329282 & 5860 & 6144 & 74.620 \\
    20 & AHAur\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 0.169 & 2.153701 & 2.045107 & 6215 & 6141 & 75.460 \\
    21 & ARAur\_Nordstrom 1994V & D & 0.925 & 3.627072 & 3.117964 & 11125 & 10600 & 88.520 \\
    22 & ARAur\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.977 & 3.712529 & 3.179695 & 5346 & 5200 & 89.7 \\
    23 & IMAur\_Gulmen 1985V & D & 0.353 & 2.580614 & 2.363079 & 10350 & 5095 & 78 \\
    24 & SXAur\_Chambliss 1979V & NC & 0.5986 & 3.060873 & 2.710523 & 19200 & 14804 & 82 \\
    25 & AWCam\_Russo 1983V & NC & 0.22 & 2.281758 & 2.142056 & 9900 & 6422 & 75.36 \\
    26 & AYCam\_Williamon 2004V & D & 0.8972 & 3.580942 & 3.084681 & 7250 & 7395 & 88.465 \\
    27 & DNCam\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 2.3753 & 5.774655 & 5.167444 & 6700 & 6840 & 71.2 \\
    28 & FNCam\_Pribulla 2002V & OC & 0.222 & 2.86586 & 2.145680 & 6848 & 6700 & 71.2 \\
    29 & EMCar\_Andersen 1989V & D & 1.016 & 3.824992 & 3.206900 & 34000 & 34000 & 81.5 \\
    30 & QXCar\_Andersen 1983cv & D & 0.914 & 5.091186 & 2.718311 & 23500 & 22240 & 85.7 \\
    31 & AOCas\_Schneider 1978V & OC & 1.185 & 4.034 & 4.034 & 34700 & 35033 & 51.2 \\
    32 & MUCas\_Lacy 2004V & D & 1.019 & 4.747435 & 2.923388 & 15100 & 14750 & 87.02 \\
    33 & TWCas\_Narita 2001V & SD & 0.432 & 2.742677 & 2.480979 & 10500 & 5400 & 74.7 \\
    34 & V459Cas\_Lacy 2004V & D & 0.974 & 3.806169 & 3.128686 & 9141 & 9099 & 89.465 \\
    35 & V523Cas\_Samec 2005V & OC & 0.52 & 2.983 & 2.604839 & 4762 & 5104 & 85.39 \\
    36 & LZCen\_Vaz 1995bv & D & 1.09 & 3.950986 & 3.343726 & 26430 & 26500 & 72.22 \\
    37 & SZCen\_Gronbech 1977V & D & 1.016 & 3.77775954 & 3.231265 & 8000 & 8280 & 88.08 \\
    38 & V346Cen\_Gimenez 1986bv & D & 0.71 & 4.677327 & 2.511337 & 26500 & 24000 & 83.9 \\
    39 & V753Cen\_Barone 1993V & OC & 3.15 & 6.814164 & 6.193046 & 5955 & 6221 & 81.660 \\
    40 & V752Cen\_Leung 1976V & OC & 3.344 & 7.067997 & 6.444314 & 6210 & 6300 & 83.18 \\
    41 & V757Cen\_Maceroni 1984V & OC & 1.49 & 4.511196 & 3.934232 & 5927 & 6000 & 69.31 \\
    42 & AHCep\_Holmgren 1990V & D & 0.877 & 3.547218 & 3.060365 & 29900 & 28570 & 29.21 \\
    43 & CWCep\_Clausen 1991bv & D & 0.94 & 3.769554 & 3.080072 & 28300 & 27700 & 82.5 \\
    44 & EKCep\_Hill 1984V & D & 0.55 & 3.363822 & 2.504025 & 8995 & 5689 & 89.16 \\
    45 & GKCep\_Niarchos 1991V & NC & 0.92 & 3.618779 & 3.111993 & 9500 & 9000 & 73.5 \\
    46 & NYCep\_Ahn 1992V & D & 0.72 & 6.524666 & 2.389262 & 28800 & 23000 & 77.39 \\
    47 & V497Cep\_Yakut 2003V & D & 0.782 & 3.386104 & 2.944357 & 19500 & 17756 & 57.9 \\
    48 & TWCet\_Russo 1982V & OC & 1.664 & 4.758601 & 4.183495 & 5400 & 5600 & 85 \\
    49 & CWCMa\_Terrell 1992V & D & 0.944 & 3.658419 & 3.140597 & 10800 & 10300 & 83.3 \\
    50 & FZCMa\_Moffat 1983V & D & 1.00 & 3.75 & 3.206796 & 22000 & 20596 & 87.63 \\
    51 & GZCMa\_Popper 1985V & D & 0.909 & 3.600561 & 3.098834 & 8810 & 8531 & 86.6 \\
    52 & SWCMa\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.914 & 5.4043 & 2.680445 & 8500 & 8500 & 88.72 \\
    53 & TYCrA\_Casey 1998V & D & 0.521 & 2.915985 & 2.60621 & 12000 & 4900 & 83 \\
    54 & RTCrB\_Sabby 2003V & D & 1.011 & 3.757853 & 3.223625 & 5075 & 5781 & 84.9 \\
    55 & AlCru\_Bell 1987V & NC & 0.61 & 3.081744 & 2.725534 & 24200 & 17660 & 81 \\
    56 & DKCyg\_Mochnacki 1972V & OC & 0.325 & 2.520836 & 2.319312 & 7200 & 7200 & 82 \\
    57 & MRCyg\_Linnell 1998V & SD & 0.399 & 2.676056 & 2.432628 & 20900 & 13900 & 84.4 \\
    58 & SWCyg\_Wilson 1988V & DC & 0.3664 & 8.938885 & 2.383622 & 9070 & 3813 & 82.7 \\
    59 & V1073Cyg\_Ahn 1992V & OC & 0.32 & 2.510013 & 2.311367 & 6856 & 6740 & 69.4 \\
    60 & V1143Cyg\_VanHamme 1984V & D & 0.9792 & 8.379136 & 2.565819 & 6550 & 6496 & 87.035 \\
    61 & V1425Cyg\_Hill 1993V & NC & 0.641 & 3.138012 & 3.134766 & 15230 & 11733 & 71.15 \\
    62 & V380Cyg\_Guinan 2000V & D & 0.626 & 4.034862 & 2.469972 & 21350 & 20500 & 82.4 \\
    63 & V382Cyg\_Harries 1997V & OC & 0.7418 & 3.316565 & 2.894341 & 36000 & 35000 & 84.5 \\
    64 & V442Cyg\_Lacy 1987V & D & 0.902 & 3.58893 & 3.090443 & 6900 & 6725 & 86 \\
    65 & V470Cyg\_Russo 1982V & D & 0.877 & 3.547218 & 3.060365 & 21100 & 1961 & 50 \\
    66 & V477Cyg\_Degirmenci 2003V & D & 0.677 & 3.202518 & 2.812357 & 36100 & 34758 & 85.7 \\
    67 & V478Cyg\_Sezer 1983V & D & 0.9717 & 3.824019 & 3.116297 & 30900 & 30308 & 78.07 \\
    68 & V541Cyg\_Lacy 1998V & D & 1.00 & 7.421249 & 2.624289 & 9885 & 9954 & 89.88 \\
    69 & V729Cyg\_Leung 1978V & OC & 0.23 & 2.305774 & 2.160058 & 34300 & 22735 & 68.18 \\
    70 & V836Cyg\_Breinhorst 1989V & NC & 0.33 & 2.531613 & 2.327215 & 10333 & 6000 & 8.08 \\
    71 & V885Cyg\_Lacy 2004V & D & 1.1142 & 3.933351 & 3.38026 & 7950 & 8375 & 7.064 \\
    72 & V909Cyg\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.886 & 3.562265 & 3.071213 & 9705 & 8790 & 89.2 \\
    73 & BSDra\_Russo 1981V & D & 0.999 & 3.748375 & 3.20562 & 6750 & 6740 & 89.4 \\
    74 & EFDra\_Pribulla 2001V & OC & 0.16 & 2.129956 & 2.026929 & 6000 & 6054 & 78.13 \\
    75 & FUDra\_Vanco 2001V & OC & 3.9841 & 7.891422 & 7.260916 & 5800 & 6133 & 78.64 \\
    76 & RZDra\_Kreiner 1994V & C & 0.396 & 2.669927 & 2.428173 & 8150 & 4898 & 87 \\
    77 & UZDra\_Lacy 1989V & D & 0.92 & 3.618799 & 3.111993 & 6100 & 5844 & 89.32 \\
    78 & ASEri\_VanHamme 1984V & SD & 0.1144 & 2.002505 & 1.928049 & 8500 & 5000 & 80.018 \\
    79 & TZFor\_Andersen 1991V & D & 0.951 & 3.669932 & 3.148912 & 6470 & 4960 & 85.67 \\
    80 & AFGem\_Maxted 1995V & SD & 0.342 & 2.557294 & 2.346025 & 10000 & 5400 & 87.4 \\
    81 & ADHer\_Mardirossian 1980V & SD & 0.33 & 2.531613 & 2.327215 & 8610 & 3900 & 84.1 \\
    82 & DIHer\_Popper 1982V & D & 0.88 & 7.181783 & 2.519301 & 17000 & 15100 & 89.3 \\
    83 & V624Her\_Popper 1984V & D & 0.825 & 3.459566 & 2.997222 & 8150 & 7940 & 79.4 \\
    84 & V728Her\_Nelson 1995V & OC & 5.5991 & 9.8987 & 9.257568 & 6622 & 6787 & 69.2 \\
    85 & V899Her\_Ozdermir 2002V & OC & 0.566 & 3.000627 & 2.667176 & 5700 & 5500 & 65.772 \\
    86 & AlHya\_Popper 1988V & D & 0.923 & 4.780037 & 2.776981 & 7096 & 6699 & 90 \\
    87 & Chi2Hya\_Clausen\&Nordstrom 1978V & D & 0.73 & 3.295982 & 2.879543 & 11550 & 11100 & 77.9 \\
    88 & HSHya\_Torres 1997V & D & 0.971 & 3.702721 & 3.172606 & 6500 & 6400 & 85.56 \\
    89 & KWHya\_Andersen 1984bv & D & 0.753 & 3.709655 & 2.761849 & 8000 & 6881 & 87.65 \\
    90 & RSInd\_Hilditch 1988V & NC & 0.322 & 2.514348 & 2.31455 & 7200 & 4659 & 90 \\
    91 & V364Lac\_Torres 1999V & D & 1.016 & 5.399183 & 2.811273 & 8251 & 8500 & 89.19 \\
    92 & EXLeo\_Pribulla 1988V & OC & 0.199 & 2.230239 & 2.103257 & 6330 & 6167 & 61.1 \\
    93 & TXLeo\_Srivastava 1968V & D & 0.375 & 2.810022 & 2.325959 & 8810 & 6476 & 66.8 \\
    94 & UVLeo\_Frederik 1996V & D & 0.965 & 3.6929 & 3.165508 & 5920 & 5821 & 82.63 \\
    95 & UZLeo\_Bradatreet 2004V & OC & 0.303 & 2.472848 & 2.28404 & 7250 & 7250 & 83 \\
    96 & TLMi\_Cester 1979V & SD & 0.1 & 1.959104 & 1.8938 & 9860 & 5055 & 86.3 \\
    97 & GGLup\_Andersen 1993V & D & 0.61 & 3.669024 & 2.53152 & 14000 & 11200 & 86.75 \\
    98 & SWLyn\_Broadstreet 2004V & NC & 0.524 & 2.921685 & 2.610318 & 6700 & 4220 & 82 \\
    99 & UULyn\_Yamasaki 1983V & NC & 0.41 & 2.698423 & 2.448877 & 6700 & 3500 & 83 \\
    100 & UVLyn\_Vanko 2001V & OC & 2.7248 & 6.249339 & 5.634983 & 6045 & 6262 & 66.8 \\
    101 & FLLyn\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.786 & 3.392981 & 2.949301 & 6152 & 5297 & 86.3 \\
    102 & TZMen\_Andersen 1987V & D & 0.604 & 3.190981 & 2.664619 & 10400 & 7200 & 88.73 \\
    103 & UXMen\_Andersen 1989V & D & 0.968 & 3.708102 & 3.163838 & 6194 & 6152 & 89.6 \\
    104 & ARMon\_Popper 1976V & D & 1.062 & 3.850078 & 3.301308 & 4200 & 5800 & 86 \\
    105 & DDMon\_Qian 1997V & SD & 0.45 & 2.778437 & 2.506876 & 6600 & 5118 & 76.5 \\
    106 & DDMon\_Yamasaki 1990V & SD & 0.697 & 3.237989 & 2.837854 & 6600 & 5514 & 79.26 \\
    107 & FSMon\_Lacy 2000V & D & 0.8959 & 3.578777 & 3.08312 & 6715 & 6550 & 87.7 \\
    108 & VVMon\_Popper 1988V & D & 1.062 & 3.850078 & 3.301308 & 4200 & 5800 & 86 \\
    109 & TUMus\_Wilson 1981V & OC & 0.7207 & 3.279704 & 2.86784 & 33600 & 29194 & 75.87 \\
    110 & TVMus\_Hilditch 1989V & OC & 0.135 & 2.061727 & 1.974287 & 5980 & 6088 & 78.9 \\
    111 & V1010Oph\_Leung 1974V & NC & 0.487 & 2.850776 & 2.559166 & 7500 & 5100 & 86.05 \\
    112 & V2388Oph\_Rodriguez 1998V & OC & 0.186 & 2.197533& 2.078487 & 6450 & 6130 & 83.9 \\
    113 & V451Oph\_Clausen 1986V & OC & 0.85 & 3.549319 & 3.004555 & 10800 & 10000 & 85.9 \\
    114 & V502Oph\_Maceroni 1982V & D & 2.985 & 6.596452 & 5.977753 & 5954 & 6200 & 71.67 \\
    115 & V508Oph\_Lapasset 1990V & OC & 0.53 & 2.933059 & 2.618516 & 6000 & 5830 & 86.13 \\
    116 & EWOri\_Popper 1986V & D & 0.97 & 3.989242 & 3.046496 & 5970 & 5781 & 89.65 \\
    117 & GCOri\_Torres 2000V & D & 0.9982 & 4.885313 & 2.859927 & 9950 & 9950 & 89.24 \\
    118 & V1031Ori\_Andersen 1990V & D & 1.034 & 4.755166 & 2.94946 & 6310 & 5010 & 88.45 \\
    119 & IQPer\_Lacy 1985V & D & 0.493 & 3.411177 & 2.470213 & 12300 & 8100 & 89.3 \\
    120 & ALPhe\_Andersen 1988V & D & 1.034 & 4.755166 & 2.94946 & 6310 & 5010 & 88.45 \\
    121 & ZetaPhe\_Clausen 1976V & D & 0.649 & 3.191342 & 2.757983 & 14000 & 11700 & 87.7 \\
    122 & VZPsc\_Hrivnak 1995V & NC & 0.8 & 3.416971 & 2.966562 & 4500 & 4110 & 48 \\
    123 & PVPup\_Vaz 1984V & D & 0.993 & 3.949822 & 3.102736 & 6920 & 6931 & 83.09 \\
    124 & UZPup\_Malasan 1989V & OC & 0.85 & 3.501861 & 3.027682 & 8150 & 7300 & 84.0 \\
    125 & VPup\_Andersen 1983V & SD & 0.53 & 2.933059 & 2.618516 & 27000 & 24354 & 79 \\
    126 & RZPyx\_Bell 1987V & NC & 0.82 & 3.451072 & 2.991107 & 17000 & 16760 & 87.4 \\
    127 & TyPyx\_Andersen 1981bV & D & 0.98 & 3.717427 & 3.183237 & 5400 & 5340 & 87.88 \\
    128 & VVPyx\_Andersen 1984V & D & 1.00 & 4.172674 & 3.034401 & 9506 & 9506 & 88.075 \\
    129 & RTScl\_Broadstreet 2004V & C & 0.433 & 2.744674 & 2.482426 & 7000 & 5200 & 79 \\
    130 & V701Sco\_Bell 1987V & OC & 0.99 & 3.733732 & 3.195028 & 23500 & 23500 & 65 \\
    131 & V760Sco\_Andersen 1985bV & D & 0.928 & 3.737653 & 3.071251 & 16900 & 16300 & 82.17 \\
    132 & V7906Sco\_Alencar 1997V & D & 1.0395 & 3.820337 & 3.255917 & 10700 & 10550 & 76 \\
    133 & RZSct\_Wilson 1985V & OC & 0.277 & 6.062884 & 2.241216 & 22700 & 7500 & 83.1 \\
    134 & OUSer\_Pribulla 2002V & OC & 0.173 & 2.16413 & 2.053069 & 6380 & 5960 & 54.23 \\
    135 & V1647Sgr\_Clausen 1977V & D & 0.901 & 6.271572 & 2.590086 & 10000 & 9500 & 90 \\
    136 & V1647Sgr\_Vaz 1997V & D & 0.6993 & 3.242052 & 2.840774 & 38000 & 34117 & 65.2 \\
    137 & V526Sgr\_Lacy 1997V & D & 0.74 & 5.451516 & 2.603541 & 10100 & 8450 & 87.3 \\
    138 & CDTau\_Ribas 1999V & D & 0.948 & 3.665 & 3.14535 & 6200 & 6200 & 87.7 \\
    139 & V471Tau\_Bradstreet 2004V & D & 1.107 & 3.921916 & 3.369402 & 5040 & 34500 & 80 \\
    140 & AWUMa\_Pribulla 1999V & OC & 0.0803 & 1.896344 & 1.843663 & 7175 & 7022 & 78.3 \\
    141 & TXUMa\_Maxted 1995V & SD & 0.247 & 2.345911 & 2.190033 & 12900 & 5500 & 83.5 \\
    142 & CVVel\_Clausen 1977V & D & 0.983 & 3.722322 & 3.186777 & 18200 & 18060 & 86.59 \\
    143 & DmVir\_Andersen 1984V & D & 1.004 & 3.756497 & 3.212919 & 6400 & 6400 & 89.66 \\
    144 & BPVul\_Lacy 2003V & D & 0.8105 & 3.570372 & 2.917453 & 7709 & 6775 & 87.67 \\
    145 & ERVul\_Guinan 1991V & D & 0.9615 & 3.687165 & 3.161363 & 6050 & 6016 & 88.3 \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate source of the warning message is the following code towards the end of the instruction `\tablefirsthead{...}`:

```
... & \tbsp $i$ \\ \hline\tbsp
```

It's that last `\tbsp` instruction, which isn't followed by `\\`, that's giving you grief. I suggest omitting that final `\tbsp` instruction.

Ditto for `\tablehead`, by the way.

Here's another suggestion: You only need *one* `\tbsp` instruction per line. Having nine of them on a line achieves nothing except generating lots of clutter.